# How to use sql function with CriteriaBuilder in Java?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How to use `CONVERT_TZ` function with `CriteriaBuilder` in Java Persistence? I am able to use it with Hibernate HQL like below:

```
"and CONVERT_TZ(PR.validFrom,'"+serverTZ+"','"+clientTZ+"') >= ?"
```

Current `CriteriaBuilder` like below:

```java
criteria.add(
   cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
      root.get("executionDate"),
      historyCriteria.getStartDate()
   )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use something like this:

```java
ParameterExpression<String> serverTZ = cb.parameter( String.class );
ParameterExpression<String> clientTZ = cb.parameter( String.class );
ParameterExpression<LocalDateTime> startDate = cb.parameter( LocalDateTime.class );

cb.and(
    cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
        cb.function(
            "CONVERT_TZ",
            LocalDateTime.class,
            root.get("executionDate"),
            serverTZ,
            clientTZ
        ), startDate
    ),
    // ...
);
        
entityManager.createQuery( criteria )
   .setParameter( serverTZ, "GMT" )
   .setParameter( clientTZ, "MET" )
   .setParameter( startDate, LocalDateTime.of(...) )
   .getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I don't know much about using CriteriaBuilder. Could you please tell how to specify column name("executionDate") in function and how to set parameter to this?

Comment: I have corrected the answer. The `root.get("executionDate")` should be passed as the first parameter of the function. I just forgot to add it.